# Error in .Call2("new_XStringSet_from_CHARACTER", class(x0), elementType(x0), : key 50 (char '2') not in lookup table

Tags: r, function, taxonomy

I am analyzing my data with dada2, I used 16S V3-V4 regions. the problem is am getting `"Error in .Call2("new_XStringSet_from_CHARACTER", class(x0), elementType(x0), : key 50 (char '2') not in the lookup table"` when I try to add species

```
taxa <- addSpecies(seqnochim,"C:/Users/alaak/Downloads/silva_species_assignment_v138.1.fa.gz")
```

however when I assigned taxonomy

```
taxa <- assignTaxonomy(seqnochim,"C:/Users/alaak/Downloads/silva_nr99_v138.1_wSpecies_train_set.fa.gz", 
                       multithread=TRUE)
```

it was fine and had no errors . if the noncheimeric sequence table has any problem it shouldn't work from the start
i have no clue what to do

I tried another data set it showed me the same error

Comment: What's in `seqnochim`? What class is it? The function `assignTaxonomy` requires a vector of sequences, whereas `addSpecies` requires the output of `assignTaxonomy` as the first argument. Now, `assignSpecies` is like `assignTaxonomy`, where the first argument is a vector of sequences.

Comment: you are right, it is my mistake thank you so much